# MinGW error "undefined reference to .."

Tags: fortran, mingw

I have attached an image of the errors that I have been receiving when I try to run the simplest fortran code.

[image: error image]

I have tried running it with codeblocks as well as with the MSYS interface and both give me these same sets of errors. I have reinstalled it numerous times with no help. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please do not upload images. Copy the errors and your commands as text. See [ask] and take tge [Tour].

Comment: @Masoud The point of that rep limit for image pasting is to stop new askers posting important stuff as images. By you are just circumventing that limit but we need them to learn they should dona copy and paste of the text.

Comment: @VladimirF I think important stuff would be data or the code as you cannot copy/paste them and replicate the problem. I personally don't think you need to copy/paste the error and it does not fall into important stuff.

Comment: @Masoud Other people with the same problem will not find the question by searching. Either by a search engine or by searching on StackOverflow internally. The error message is as important as the code to me.

Comment: Understand your concern. @VladimirF